# VBA || Transpose unique values and Sums

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to make a map that transposes unique values from a column and populate this new list with some parameters from another table,

[image: Table]

the result on this map should be the following

[image: List]

I've already have the code for the unique values as follows:

```
Dim d As Object
Dim c As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    c = Range("B2:B" & lr)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
    d(c(i, 1)) = 1

    Next i
Range("AK2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
```

Although for filling the amounts on the columns Base and VAT I'm having some issues trying to think on the formula, basically for "Base" the value should be the total by Document Nr of the accounts starting with 6*,7* which are a result of Dr - Cr.

I know it may sound a bit confusing, but if anyone could please help me I would be much appreciated.

Comment: A formula for **Base** that looks only at the **Dr** column might be: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)*(LEFT(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)={"6","7"})*Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7)` where your data is on `Sheet1` and your unique list of **NrDoc** starts in `A2`.  You should be able to expand this to your other requirements.  If you want a total VBA solution, I would set up a user defined object to collect all the data.  I'll check back later when I am back at my computer.

Comment: Thank you Ron,

I'm new in VbA although for me it seems to me that the better option would be to trace all the columns on the database as arrays, but for this is any way I could define a column as array, so than I can later on reference easier the Sumifs?

Comment: If you are going to use formulas, I would use dynamic named ranges for your database columns or, (my preference for the formula solution), would be to make it a Table, and use structured references to the columns.

Comment: Is there any way to define a column as an array through VbA?

Comment: Go to Chip Pearson's web site. Lots of info about VBA arrays and worksheet ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: How are you calculating VAT?

Answer (score 0):

Using @RonRosenfeld formula from comments, following might be helpful:

```
Sub Demo()

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, currLR As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rngWH As Range
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet1")   'set data sheet here
    With srcSht
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data in sheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)                'range for filter
        Set rngWH = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)              'range for formulas
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2 'column to display data
        rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytoRange:=.Cells(1, lastCol), unique:=True
        currLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row 'unique nr. doc count
        lastCol = lastCol + 1

        'formula for Base
        .Cells(1, lastCol).Value = "Base"
        .Range(.Cells(2, lastCol), .Cells(currLR, lastCol)).Formula = _
            "=SUMPRODUCT((" & .Cells(2, lastCol - 1).Address(False, False) & "=" & rngWH.Address & ")*(LEFT(" & rngWH.Offset(, 1).Address & ")={""6"",""7""})*(" & rngWH.Offset(, 2).Address & "))"

        'formula for Vat
        .Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Value = "VAT"
        'enter formula here for VAT

        'formula for Total
        .Cells(1, lastCol + 2).Value = "Total"
        .Range(.Cells(2, lastCol + 2), .Cells(currLR, lastCol + 2)).Formula = _
            "=SUMIF(" & rngWH.Address & "," & .Cells(2, lastCol - 1).Address(False, False) & "," & rngWH.Offset(, 3).Address & ")"

        .Range(.Cells(2, lastCol), .Cells(currLR, lastCol + 2)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, lastCol), .Cells(currLR, lastCol + 2)).Value
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a "pure" VBA solution, I would

- create a user defined object which as the properties of  Nr.Doc, Acct, VAT, Base and Total.
- Base, as you wrote, we detect by checking the first digit of the account
- VAT will be any amount in the Dr column that does not start with 6 or 7
- Total will be the values in the Cr column.

If your rules are different, by setting things up like this, they can be easily changed, as the code is almost self-documenting.

For the UDO, we enter a class module and rename it cDoc. 
Also, I chose to use early-binding so we set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  If you want to change it to late-binding as you do in your posted code, feel free to do that.  It can be easier if you are distributing the file; but I prefer to have the Intellisense available when I am coding.

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
'Rename this module "cDoc"
Private pDocNum As String
Private pAcct As String
Private pBase As Currency
Private pVAT As Currency
Private pTotal As Currency

Public Property Get Acct() As String
    Acct = pAcct
End Property
Public Property Let Acct(Value As String)
    pAcct = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Base() As Currency
    Base = pBase
End Property
Public Property Let Base(Value As Currency)
    pBase = Value
End Property

Public Property Get VAT() As Currency
    VAT = pVAT
End Property
Public Property Let VAT(Value As Currency)
    pVAT = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Total() As Currency
    Total = pTotal
End Property
Public Property Let Total(Value As Currency)
    pTotal = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DocNum() As String
    DocNum = pDocNum
End Property
Public Property Let DocNum(Value As String)
    pDocNum = Value
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'   you can change this to late binding if everything works

Sub ReOrganizeTable()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dDoc As Dictionary, cD As cDoc
    Dim I As Long
    Dim V As Variant

'Set source and results worksheets
'Read source data into variant array

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            Set wsRes = Worksheets.Add(after:=wsSrc)
            wsRes.Name = "Results"
        Case Is <> 0
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
            Stop
    End Select
On Error GoTo 0
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Gather and organize the data
Set dDoc = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cD = New cDoc
    With cD
        .DocNum = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Acct = CStr(vSrc(I, 2))
        Select Case Left(.Acct, 1)
            Case 6, 7
                .Base = vSrc(I, 3)
            Case Else
                .VAT = vSrc(I, 3)
        End Select
        .Total = vSrc(I, 4)

        If Not dDoc.Exists(.DocNum) Then
            dDoc.Add Key:=.DocNum, Item:=cD
        Else
            dDoc(.DocNum).Base = dDoc(.DocNum).Base + .Base
            dDoc(.DocNum).VAT = dDoc(.DocNum).VAT + .VAT
            dDoc(.DocNum).Total = dDoc(.DocNum).Total + .Total
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Size results array
ReDim vRes(0 To dDoc.Count, 1 To 4)

'Headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Nr Doc"
vRes(0, 2) = "Base"
vRes(0, 3) = "VAT"
vRes(0, 4) = "Total"

'Populate the data area
I = 0
For Each V In dDoc.Keys
    I = I + 1
    Set cD = dDoc(V)
    With cD
        vRes(I, 1) = .DocNum
        vRes(I, 2) = .Base
        vRes(I, 3) = .VAT
        vRes(I, 4) = .Total
    End With
Next V

'write and format the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

### Results

Using your original posted data

[image]